# How to get Absolute path for a video using ALAssets Library?

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

Its simple, How can i get an absolute path for a video retrieved using ALAssets Library? I want to upload this video as file attachment using ASI framework.

It works if i use UIImagePickerViewController. But thats NOT an option any more. I also dont want to use NSData or copy-pasting video to temp file. Need a smart solution? Anybody ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the absolute path (file system path) for a video you retrieved using the AssetsLibrary-Framework. The simple reason for that is that these files are outside your app's sandbox and you can't access them directly. You need to use the getBytes-Method of ALAssetsRepresentation to get the byte data of the video file. Most likely you will have to save this data to a temp file, before you can attach it to an email.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALAssetPropertyAssetURL`. From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Property_Keys):

- The key to retrieve a URL identifier for the asset.
- The corresponding value is an NSURL object.
- This URL is used by the library-change notifications to identify assets and asset groups. Only the ALAssetRepresentation and ALAssetsGroup classes support this property.

So, once you get `ALAsset` object  you can get url like this:

```
 asset.defaultRepresentation.url
```